# Powershell replace a substring according to regex

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, how can I replace the following string

```
"\\10.10.10.5\Program Files (x86)\Foo"
```

into this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foo"
```

I need to replace only if `\\IP` was detected in the beginning of the string

**EDIT**

The IP can be any IP so it should be detected by some RegEx in the format of `\\X.X.X.X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"\\10.10.10.5\Program Files (x86)\Foo" -replace "\\\\10.10.10.5", "c:"
```

after your comment, please try this one :

```
"\\10.10.10.5\Program Files (x86)\Foo" -replace "\\\\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", "c:"
```

Comment: Will not help, The IP is not hardcoded, and can be any IP

Comment: you should have mention that in your question !